# How do i concatenate my database column query in the controller with a folder in public path of laravel 5.2 for my pdf multiple downloads

Tags: laravel

```
class downloadController extends Controller
{
    public function getDownload(){
        $pdfFile = DB::table('computer')->select('pdfFile')->get();
        $pathToFile = public_path(). "/sportsPDF/$pdfFile";
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/pdf',
        );
        return response()->download($pathToFile);
    }
}
```

computer is my database name'
pdfFile is my column name which i stored all the pdf file names
sportsPDF is the folder under public folder which i include my pdf files.
the error message is "Array to string conversion"

Answer (score 0):

try `first()` not `get()` 
( `get()` returns array of results )

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries